# Storing datetime values in Shapefiles using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, datetime

I have a shapefile with date in a `string` field. I create a new field with `date` type and use the calculator to make the conversion. But the result only provide the date part, the time part is removed. Even when the preview show the correct conversion.

Here you can see the original string field `time` and the result date `time2`. And the use of the conversion function `to_datetime()` and the preview result at the end

[image]

If you go to the layer properties you can change the edit mode to date/time. Then if go to the data and try to edit `time2` you get the **current** date/time. So is possible save date and time in the same field. But the update tool still **doesn't** work as expected

[image]

---

As J.R said. Even when you can change QGIS edit to allow Date/Time the save to shapefile will discard the time.

Comment: The `Date` field only allows you to store up to 10 characters, enough for `YYYY-MM-DD`. If you want to also store the time, use a `String` field instead and set a larger character length value :)

Comment: @Joseph Im confused, the file is a shapefile from esri, and my understanding is date field can store date and time  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/arcgis-field-data-types.htm

Comment: Esri didn't create the dBase format (Ashton-Tate did, in the early 1980s; at the time, they were considered forward-thinking for using four bytes to store years). If you want second-resolution time datatype, you need to use a geodatabase format (Personal, File or Enterprise)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As joseph said in comment you can't store date and time in a single field of a shapefile, you could :

-use a string field (as Joseph said)

-use two field (one for date and one for time...)

-use another file format that support DateTime fieldtype to store your data

Comment: Im confused, the file is a shapefile from esri, and my understanding is date field can store date and time  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/arcgis-field-data-types.htm

Comment: that's true for geodatabase but not for shapefile

Comment: Please check my edit on the question.

Comment: I try to replicate your edit but after saving the time part is removed....

Comment: you should chek this ESRI page http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISDesktop/com/Gp_ToolRef/geoprocessing_tool_reference/geoprocessing_considerations_for_shapefile_output.htm  about shapefile limitation it state that it is not possible to store date and time in the same field. Also I try to replicate your edit trick but the time is remove from the field afer saving the edit....

Comment: I see thanks. Looks like I should use a geodatabase instead.

Comment: NOBODY should use a geodatabase. Use a standard format like geopackage or spatialite instead.

Comment: @ndawson What you mean? That is the standard for esri.

Comment: If you're looking for interoperability with qgis then geodatabase is a bad move. While qgis can open them, it's read only and much slower than the alternative formats.