# Writing Datetimes with Fortran in Shapefiles

Tags: qgis, shapefile, datetime, fortran

I'm writing shapefiles nicely with Fortran. One of the fields I'm writing is a Date field. I read several things online that seem conflicting, wondering if I could get some clarification.

The dBASE file has a Date input, I can easily work with this. Fields are however limited to 10 bytes, so there is no room for time. And altering the field inside of QGIS just leads to the time not being saved (why does it even exist in QGIS then?). So I get the same issue as [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267413/storing-datetime-values-in-shapefiles) and similar things. I also found [here](http://www.dbase.com/Knowledgebase/INT/db7_file_fmt.htm) that a datetime format is accepted with dBASE but this doesn't seem to get recognized in QGIS (I know the link seems to imply it only works in FoxPro but it was worth a shot). I'm additionally confused by [this page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/time/supported-field-formats.htm) which suggests that time is no problem for ArcGIS, (which is obviously not QGIS but they use the same .dbf files, I'm also writing these file for use in ArcGIS).

My question boils down to this: I guess Date+Time is a bit of an issue with the .dbf file, so my options are to basically store the time as a string ("*When visualizing data through time, you must specify the Time field that contains the time values. These time values can be stored in date, string, or numeric field types. For best performance, it is recommended that you store your time values in a date field type*"). The last link makes me think that ArcGIS can still work with this (I'd like to be able to create time-based visualizations with the time slider, etc.). I just can't find what format to put it in when I save the time as a string and if there is any special indicator I'd need to set in the .dbf header or something, and will ArcGIS or QGIS be able to obtain the time information despite the column being a string column. I want to be able to do this all through Fortran, without actually changing any settings in ArcGIS or QGIS. I'm trying to automate this process through Fortran and I'm really close, this is the last bit.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. dBase III+ does **not** support time in the date type. Period. End of story. Any references you saw in ArcGIS documentation to datetime types were referring to file or other geodatabase.

Comment: Nice! Fortran!!!