# Using field calculator unable to keep time and date format

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, datetime

I was looking to keep the date/time as is when using field calculator to keep the format as I'm not able to maintain the time in the new field "da". This is what I get when trying to do so. I tried searching for solutions, but to no avail so far.

Update based on comments:

I'm using field calculator to solve this.
I'm calculating into a date field from string field.
Data source is a shapefile

[image]

Comment: are you using python in the field calculator? this may be helpful... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

Comment: I had to create a text field.  It would not add the time into a date field.  Are you calculating into a text field or a date field?

Comment: And what is your data source, a SHP file, FGDB, SDE...?

Comment: I've updated my question to answer all questions in the top comments above.I'm using field calculator to solve this.
I'm calculating into a date field from string field.
Data source is a shapefile

Comment: Shapefiles use dBase's date type, which does not support time. You *cannot* preserve time in the shapefile format.

Comment: Sounds good @Vince

Comment: Can your "da" field be a type text "string" or does it have to be type date?

Comment: Also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267413/storing-datetime-values-in-shapefiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Is `ShotDate` as string field?
- Is `da` a date field?
- Are you copying `ShortDate` to `da`? And if so how (Field calculator with VB Script)?
- Can you enlarge the column size of the da field and check if the value has a time component

If `da` is the date field and this is the field you want to have the formatting I believe that is all controlled at the Windows level.

From [fundamentals-of-date-fields](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/fundamentals-of-date-fields.htm):

> Settings on your Windows system determine how the dates are displayed in ArcMap—M/d/yy, MM/dd/yy, yy/MM/dd, and so on. ArcMap uses the system short date format (numerical) for displaying dates.