# Datetime on attribute tables

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, fields-attributes, date, datetime

I have written a script to add, among other stuff, a datetime column.
I have used the `arcpy.AddField_management`command, but it didn't have a 'Datetime' type, so I used the 'Date' type : `arcpy.AddField_management(outZStat,"Datetime", "DATE")`
Bellow is a part of the script:

```
mth = raster[21:23]
dec = raster[30]
tm = 14
s2 =  str(day)
s3 = "/"
s4 = str(mth)
s5 = "/"
s6 = str(yr)
s7 = str(" 14:00")
str_dt = s2 +s3 +s4 +s5 +s6+s7
datet = datetime.strptime(str_dt, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
print datet
```

I added the print just to be sure about the values of `datet`, its gives me exactly what I want:
[image]

However, in the attribute table, the time is 00:00:00 for all the attributes in the Datetime field:
[image]

Screen of the 1st row of my table:
[image]

The problem may be coming from the type on the `arcpy.AddField_management`but I don't know how to 'force' the Datetime.

The script:

`...    arcpy.AddField_management(outZStat,"Datetime", "DATE")
...     arcpy.AddField_management(outZStat,"Year", "SHORT")
...     arcpy.AddField_management(outZStat,"Month", "SHORT")
...     arcpy.AddField_management(outZStat,"Decade", "SHORT")
...     arcpy.AddField_management(outZStat,"Time", "SHORT")
...

...

...     mylist = []
...     with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(outZStat, '*') as arows:
...         idx = arows.fields.index("OID")
...         for arow in arows:
...             mylist.append(arow[idx])
...     mylist_length = len(mylist)
...     with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(outZStat, "*") as cursor:
...         i = 0
...         for row in cursor:
...             if i< mylist_length:
...                 if raster[6] == "A":
...                     if raster[30]=="1":
...                         day = 01
...                     elif raster[30]=="2":
...                         day = 11
...                     else:
...                         day = 21
...

...                     yr = raster[16:20]
...                     mth = raster[21:23]
...                     dec = raster[30]
...                     tm = 14
...                     s2 =  str(day)
...                     s3 = "/"
...                     s4 = str(mth)
...                     s5 = "/"
...                     s6 = str(yr)
...                     s7 = str(" 14:00")
...                     str_dt = s2 +s3 +s4 +s5 +s6+s7
...                     datet = datetime.strptime(str_dt, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
...                     print datet
...                 else:
...

...                     if raster[31]=="1":
...                         day = 01
...                     elif raster[31]=="2":
...                         day = 11
...                     else:
...                         day = 21
...                     yr = raster[17:21]
...                     mth = raster[22:24]
...                     dec = raster[31]
...                     tm = 10
...                     s2 =  str(day)
...                     s3 = "/"
...                     s4 = str(mth)
...                     s5 = "/"
...                     s6 = str(yr)
...                     s7 = str(" 10:00")
...                     str_dt = s2 +s3 +s4 +s5 +s6+s7
...                     datet = datetime.strptime(str_dt, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
...                     print datet
...

...                 id = cursor.fields.index("OID")
...                 row = [id, cursor[1],cursor[2],cursor[3],cursor[4],cursor[5],cursor[6],datet,yr,mth,dec,tm]
...                 cursor.updateRow(row)
...                 i = i +1`

[EDIT:] What's different in my question, comparing to the question [Storing datetime values in Shapefiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267413/storing-datetime-values-in-shapefiles), is that fields in the attribute tables in ArcGis, don't have a "Datetime" type (they have only Date type, in opposition to those in qgis). Ther isn't either the "to_datetime" function in the field calculator of ArcGis.

The easiest method to resolve my problem is to turn the field type of my attribute table to string. That's what I did finally.

Comment: Just with the script cited, with a datetime.strptime()

Comment: yes, I used the InsertCursor and UpdateCursor. It's working but my problem actually is on the datetime itself

Comment: it's too long, I'll add it in my question

Comment: The data is a table generated by zonal statistics as table from a shapefile and a TIFF. I added some columns to use them forward (with datetime)

Comment: All right, so there is any other solution to show time in the attibute tables? it's kind of crucial in my case and I really don't know how to do it. I'm sorry

Comment: Your code snippet is difficult to follow/debug. Have you tried right clicking the field - Calculate Field - choose python parser and code `datetime.datetime.now( )`? If the time is added then you are making some error in your code

Comment: "there is a failure during processing", that's what it showed me. Sorry for the code. I can Maybe send you my intire code? that's just an extract drom 4 pages

Comment: Maybe has this question to migrate to StackOverflow?

Comment: The problem is your code sample. It is not reproducable and impossible to debug for anyone but you. "When seeking help to debug/write/improve code always provide the desired behavior, a specific problem/error and the shortest code (as formatted text, not pictures) needed to reproduce it in the question body"

Comment: Oh ok, i'll try to make it reproducible.
Thanks a lot

Comment: I've finally just used string type in the datetime field: 
 `arcpy.AddField_management(outZStat,"Datetime", "TEXT")`
Visually, it's of course exactly what I wanted, but it's a string. In itself, it's not a problem. I'm using the data stored in this table with another script that converts the strings to dates (`datetime.strftime()`) and order them in ascending order to generate time series and plot them. Thanks a lot @BERA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing datetime values in Shapefiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267413/storing-datetime-values-in-shapefiles)

Comment: Shapefiles (dbf format) does not support time. Date type in gdb does.