# Apply a date filter to the vector layer

Tags: qgis, python, filter, qgsvectorlayer, qgsexpression

I am new to developement in QGIS. I use a the 3.4.4 version of QGIS.
My vector layer is like this:
[image: vector layer data]

So I want to know how to filter this data by date and apply the changes in the GUI. Here is what I tried but it is not working:

```
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()
for layer_id, layer in layers.items():
    idx= layer.fields().indexFromName("dateposte")
    values = layer.uniqueValues( idx )
    expr = QgsExpression("dateposte" LIKE '2019-02%')
    for f in layer.getFeatures():
        f[idx] = expr.evaluate( f )
```

**EDIT:
I change this code and can find how many of the point pass the filter, the trouble is that there is no change in the map. So can anyone show me how to apply the filter in the vector on the map? Here is the new code**

```
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()
for layer_id, layer in layers.items():
    if (layer.name() == "csv_points_acc") or (layer.name() == "csv_points_amb"):
        print(layer.name())
        expression = """"dateposte" like '%2019-01%'"""
        request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(expression)
        matches = 0
        for f in layer.getFeatures(request):
           matches += 1
        print(matches)
```

Comment: Date fields are tricky, it depends on the underlying storage. Is your dateposte a datetime field or text field? Here's a link https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/sql-reference-for-query-expressions-used-in-arcgis.htm#GUID-85C03D85-F4A5-48FC-8E8C-3F79919430DB it's Esri but the SQL is mostly the same between Esri and QGIS as the query is passed to the database driver. The LIKE filter only works on text which may be why you're having problems, have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267413/storing-datetime-values-in-shapefiles-using-qgis

Comment: Thanks, dateposte is a string. Is it possible to convert it to datetime?

Comment: `to_datetime` does this - in the field calculator. I don't know, how Python handles this. But, you could run `to_datetime` on your layer prior to executing your code.

Comment: ok, I'll try it and give feedback after

Comment: After reading the second link you shared, I think it is better to keep the dateposte to string cause datetime can't store more than 10 characters. So it' s necessary to find out how to make the filter work with the string type.

Comment: As for converting string to a date type I've had success in Esri using python datetime object with string.split(): datetime.date(int(StringValue.split(' ').split('-')[0]),int(StringValue.split(' ').split('-')[1]),int(StringValue.split(' ').split('-')[2])) will convert your string into a datetime date object which can be assigned to a date field. There is no reason why you couldn't add fields for year, month, day, hour, min and second then make a more complex query for each of those fields; from your example you're not using the time portion so perhaps that's not needed and a date field is ok.

Comment: "It's not working" tells us nothing. What *does* happen?  Was there an application/software crash, was there an error message (if so what was the complete error message as text, not screenshot), did the program run but produce incorrect/unexpected results (if so what were they)?

Comment: @MichaelStimson `datetime.datetime.strptime` is the definitive date parser. No need for all those splits with a `'%Y-%m-%d'` format string. The only tricky part is that it uses the local host's default timezone, so if you want GMT/UTC you need to add a `.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)`

Comment: @user2856 first of all, there is no change in the map, I think that only the points that pass the filter should be displayed in the map which is not in my case.

Comment: Thank you for that @Vince, that's something I didn't know. I'll be using that function to parse date and/or time strings from now on.