# QGIS field-calculator time formating produces NULL

Tags: field-calculator, attribute-table, null

I'm struggling to format a QString attribute field to a DateTime or Date field.
I've been trying the built in functions `to_date` `to_time` `to_datetime` of QGIS 3.10.14 and none of them seem to do the trick. The layer unit is meter not degrees. I even created a spatial index, not knowing whether it would help. I saved the changes on the layer, of the project.

The result is always the same - the created field is `NULL`.  I seem to overlook something fundamental. The weirdest part that the Field Calculator shows a valid result, as displayed in the image below.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you use the Refactor Fields tool to change the field format?

Comment: @johns: thanks for the suggestion, didn't know this tool. 
Tried it - in the temp layer refactoring works fine. when saving the refactored fields are ```NULL```again.

Comment: What is your target field type?  The tools save to a geopackage if no output is specified and that may impose some constraints.  If you save the refactored fields result to a shapefile and then export that to your final field type does that work?  Can you run the tool to save directly to your final type instead of a temporary layer?

Comment: I faced a similar problem a few days ago while digitizing points and creating a timestamp using the now() expression. Was working with a shapefile and whenever I saved the edits, the field would return to NULL. Not sure if it's the file format that is the problem but anyway, I solved it by creating a text field as it was sufficient for my case.

Comment: @johns: I tried both,saving "temp" and to a "geopkg".

Comment: @Techie_Gus: unfortunately I wanted to use the times to calculate time differences. Then style the layer uppon those differences. 
- I worked around with excel -

Comment: @Velester.  Check this out for ways to get around the shapefile limitation for storing dates, such as using two fields, one for day and one for time.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267413/storing-datetime-values-in-shapefiles-using-qgis